# How to remove/delete inserted Yeoman Excel Developer Add-ins?

Tags: excel, office-js, manifest, office-addins, excel-web-addins

I am developing customer functions with Yeoman for Excel Add-in.
We can use cmd, the npm run build to build add-in and insert to excel, and we also can insert the add-in by upload the "manifest".
But once we uploaded/insert the add-ins, how can we remove/delete the developer add-ins we don't use/want anymore?

The developer Add-ins shows:
[image]

Once I clicked to "See All", I can not see any developer Add-ins:
[image]

Then I tried to find/delete the developer add-ins from options add-ins part, I still can not find it and delete it.
[image]

I also tried the online version excel, also can not delete the add-ins I don't want anymore...

Does anyone know what can I do?
Thanks!

Comment: Try to clear the "WEF Cache". Look for the Clear button in the File > Options > Trust Center Settings > Trusted Add-in Catalogs page.

Comment: Try [Clear the Office Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove an add-in that you've previously sideloaded on Windows, Mac, or iOS, you need to clear the Office cache on your computer. In your case you just need to delete the contents of the `Wef` folder. You can find it in the following path:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\
```

If the following folder exists, delete its contents too.

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\AC\#!123\INetCache\
```

Read more about that in the [Clear the Office cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache) article.

Answer (score 2):

Previous answer is really helpful. For Mac, which was my case, the path to the `Wef` folder is

```
/Users/%username%/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Documents/wef
```

The other folder doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

in the Registry you need to go  `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\WEF\Developer` and remove Add-in Guid records from right side.

Developer Add-ins section will be empty.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove it from the registry.  Search for the Add-in Guid in the Registry and remove the instance from the Registry and the Add-ins will no longer be listed in Excel.