# Need help removing an Excel Yeoman Generated Add-In

Tags: javascript, excel, office365, excel-addins, yeoman-generator

I generated an Excel Office-On-The-Web add-in using the Yeoman Generator.
Every time I open a new workbook (Book1.xlsx) the add-in auto loads.
Now I want to permanently delete the add-in.

But there is no add-in listed:

1. under Office Add-Ins in the Book1 workbook using:
   File > Add-ins > My Add-Ins (or Admin Managed)
2. in the registry as an "Open" branch in the path:
   Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options
3. or in the Microsoft Admin Center (admin.microsoft.com) as a deployed app.

---

Tried the following to:

1. Delete an add-in that was deployed:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/manage-addins-in-the-admin-center?view=o365-worldwide
2. Delete an add-in from the directory:
   %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef
   per [How to remove/delete inserted Yeoman Excel Developer Add-ins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74158721/how-to-remove-delete-inserted-yeoman-excel-developer-add-ins)
3. Delete an add-in from the Microsoft Admin Center: admin.microsoft.com

I appreciate your help in removing that add-in. Thank you.

Comment: "To remove an add-in sideloaded to Office on the web, simply clear your browser's cache. " https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/sideload-office-add-ins-for-testing

Answer (score 0):

Hi there I think I got a solution to your problem:

1. Open-up excel and load a Blank workbook.
2. Go to File > Options > Add-ins and in the bottom of the window there should be a "Manage" section where in a drop down menu "Excel Add-ins" is selected.
   [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ym6jd.png)
3. Click on "Go..."
4. Uncheck the add-on that you want to remove and hit on OK.
5. Reboot excel and everything should be alright.

Comment: FYI: I'm referring to Excel on the web projects created through the Yeoman Generator

which are different from the desktop-type add-ins that you're referring to

--like analysis toolpak, solver add-in, and such.

Check the following links:

•  Create Office Add-in projects using the Yeoman Generator:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/yeoman-generator-overview

•  Build an Excel task pane add-in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-jquery?tabs=yeomangenerator

But I appreciate your response Dimitar.